# Unable to import Cocoapod framework to Swift file that has multiple target

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I'm making an app for both iOS and WatchOS, and I'm unable to import the SwiftyJSON framework to my Swift file. I got the error `No such module 'SwiftyJSON'`. Below is a screenshot of it. Take note on the Target Membership on the right, as I needed this same file on the iOS app and also the WatchKit Extension.

[image: Failed to import SwiftyJSON]

I am able to import the framework to other files that just have "Counter" checked as Target Membership, shown below.

I'm also able to import the framework if I only checked the WatchKit Extension for the target membership. Seems like it only failed if I check both the options.

[image: Able to import framework]

And this is my Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '10.0'

def shared_pods
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'
end

target 'Counter' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  shared_pods

  target 'CounterTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'CounterUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
    end
end

target 'Counter WatchKit App' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  # Pods for Counter WatchKit App
end

target 'Counter WatchKit Extension' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  shared_pods
end
```

**UPDATE**

Nothing have changed, but after an hour of cleaning and restarting Xcode the problem went away.

Comment: Please updated question with code in text format instead of image on podfile.

Comment: I don´t know if is too obvious but you don´t have shared_pods for your Counter watchKit App in your pod file, it is intentionall?

Comment: @ReinierMelian Yup it is intentional, because I'm only using that framework for my WatchKit extension and not the watch kit app. But after shutting down Xcode for some time the problem went away. Oh well.

Comment: @ChanJingHong happens... more than should but it happens..., congrats then